# An array of strings is throwing an error for an unexpected token javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a grid for a game. I have an object `maps` that contains the level designs.
This is it:

```
var maps = {
  cave: [" ________________ ",
         "/                \",
         "|                 ", 
         "|                 ", 
         "|_________________"]
}
```

This is on github pages, by the way. Whenever I go to the console on the site, I see that it threw an error:

> "Invalid or unexpected token"

On the second array value (the third line as I have it there). Why is it doing this? Can someone help please?

EDIT: sorry, didn't know this was a duplicate. I didn't know what the problem was, so I didn't know what to search for first before asking.

Comment: Alternatively use backtics:
var maps = {
  cave: [
` ________________ 
/                \  
|                   
|                   
|_________________` 
  ]
}

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the slash on the 2nd line. If you don't escape the slash, it escapes the `"`, and this breaks the closing of the string:

```js
var maps = {
  cave: [" ________________ ",
         "/                \\",
         "|                 ", 
         "|                 ", 
         "|_________________"]
}

console.log(maps)
```